# Processing 50 GB of JSON into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have about 50 GB of 6,000 JSON files which I am currently loading into a pandas dataframe using the following method. (the **format_pandas** function sets up my pandas data frame while reading each JSON row):

```
path = '/Users/shabina.rayan/Desktop/Jupyter/Scandanavia Weather/Player  Data'
records = []
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.JSON')):
    file = Path(filename)
    with open(file) as json_data:
        j = json.load(json_data)
        format_pandas(j)
pandas_json = json.dumps(records)
df = pd.read_json(pandas_json,orient="records")
```

As can be guessed, this takes an excruciatingly long time to process my data. Does anyone have any suggestions on any other way I can process 50 GB of JSON files and visualize/analyze it?

Comment: Under the assumption that you actually append the results of `format_pandas()` (whatever that is) to `records` - why are you loading and parsing your JSON files only to serialize them back to JSON a moment later, and then parse them again through Pandas? That's extremely wasteful, especially for such a large amount of data... Why not append your data frames as you read your JSON data?

Comment: If you have 50GB of data, I would recommend that you use a binary format to store it if at all possible. If the format is uncompressed, loading will go much faster just because your size will be an order of magnitude smaller (less disk I/O) and you will have to slog through and validate so much less text (less parsing).

Comment: @zwer. I hadn't paid attention to that part. That's terrible :)

Comment: Load the data into a database and query it cleverly.

Answer (score 2):

Dump it into [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) and run queries as required.